# Allocation of memory on stack for large arrays in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, stack

I am using Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10. I stumbled across following behavior which I cannot explain:

```
void main(){
 double stack_array[120000]; //ok
}
```

```
void main(){
 double stack_array[130000]; //program has stopped working, I assume due to a stack overflow, default stack size is 1MB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx
}
```

But this works:

```
void main(){
    double stack_array1[120000];
    double stack_array2[130000];
}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Are you saying your first example has two instances of main()? In the same project?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The third example fails as well with a stack overflow with VS2015 and 1 MB stack size.

Comment: Did you use the same optimization settings in the last example?

Comment: That's strange in my case it does not fail. And no these are three separate programs

Comment: @FrankPuffer makes a good point, all of these examples work for me in Release builds. The large arrays are likely optimized out.

Comment: Indeed, when I assign values to the arrays in the 3rd example then I get the "program has stopped" message, too. So the reason seems to be optimization. Thanks @FrankPuffer and Francois Andrieux!

Comment: default stack size is 1 MB  when you use *link.exe* for build and if not use */STACK:reserve[,commit]* option. 120000*8=960000 - yet fit to 1MB when 130000*8=10400000 already more than 1MB (8==sizeof(double) ) . when no optimization *cl.exe* unconditionally call [__chkstk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648426(v=vs.85).aspx) for your array and crash in this function. if optimization used - *cl.exe* drop unused variables, as in 3-rd example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, applications compiled and linked in MSVC have a small stack size, something like 1 MB, reserved for threads by default.  You blew the stack -- you have placed more stuff on the stack than will fit.

The program helpfully notices and terminates in the first case, but not in the second case.  Maybe because you stepped over the guard they put against blowing the stack.

I don't know if MSVC is doing this, but one technique used in debug builds to deal with memory corruption is to put a token beyond the end of arrays, and check if it was overwritten when the array is destroyed.  A technique used to detect stack blowing is to protect some pages past the end of the stack, and trap them being written to or read from.

If these are happening, then if the *end* of your stack is in the protected pages, the stack blowing would be detected.  If you skip over it, it won't be detected.  If that memory you used was allocated (say, by the heap), you'd just be corrupting memory, and you won't immediately crash.

Such a non-crash would be non-deterministic, but it could be reliable on one system but not another based on how the OS in question gives memory to processes asking for it.

Naturally, in release builds, these arrays get optimized away, so I presume you are building debug.

Comment: *MSVC has a small stack size* - MSVC is absolute unrelated to this. this is *link.exe* by default set stack size to 1 MB. guard page to stack set windows always. *cl.exe* call `_chkstk` when the local variables exceed 4K/8K bytes. guard page not at the end of stack, but at the end of commited stack space. at it moved down during `_chkstk` call. until really end of reserved stack size reached - will be exception (STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW). this of course minor details, but if want be precise